# QT - Temperature Real Time Plot

Tags: c++, qt, canvas, plot, qwt

I want to make real time plot in QT. Somethink like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYGpu.jpg)

form https://www.instructables.com/id/Make-graphs-on-Qt-and-plot-your-arduino-measuremen/

This is really old and i have many problems with compiling this.

I already install QWT and change qextserialport to QSerialPort and it work fine, but there is a problem with:

```
plot->canvas()->setLineWidth( 1 );
plot->canvas()->setFrameStyle( QFrame::Box | QFrame::Plain );
plot->canvas()->setBorderRadius( 3 );
```

> widget.cpp:76: error: 'class QWidget' has no member named
>   'setLineWidth'
>        plot->canvas()->setLineWidth( 1 );

and when I comment it, I have Runtime error.

Any ideas how to fix it, or make my plot in other way?

Comment: What type is the plot variable, what is returned with plot->canvas() and what type would you expect instead?

Comment: plot is: QwtPlot *plot;